# How to handle delete action with a command handler?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I've implemented `org.eclipse.ui.edit.delete` [command handler](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/commands/AbstractHandler.html) and I want to invoke it with Edit/Delete main menu item.

As "delete" action is a [retargetable](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/wrkAdv_retarget.htm) action invoking another defined in the context of each edit, editor is usually configured with `IActionBars.setGlobalAction(String id, IAction action)` where `id` = `"delete"` and action is a custom action to be invoked by a retargetable one.

I can see following options:

1. Create an action that would delegate its execution and state change monitoring to a command 
   convert convert existing command into an argument for `setGlobalAction`, probably copying `org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction` approach.
2. Remove an existing action from the main menu and insert command contribution item instead

Both ways look too complex/dirty. Am I missing something? Can I use a command instead of action?

EDIT:

It seems that main menu is implemented not with `IAction`, but with `CommandContributionItem`. The default command handler invokes `CommandAction` which in turn queries `RetargetAction`. "Better" handler for the command can override this behavior.

While I can provide a handler for delete command now, the question is still actual as calling a command from GUI (for example by clicking on a button) is useful and custom commands are not so easy to call (they have no default key bindings or retargetable actions).

Comment: For Delete you may also need to look at `org.eclipse.ui.actions.TextActionHandler` which deals with making the delete, cut, copy and select actions work when a text control is active.

Comment: I'm editing a custom data structure, not a text.